# How to retrieve model-specific information when using the caret package?

Tags: r, caret

CARET is a convenient tool that wraps dozens of modelling methods. CARET allows the user to access performance statistics such as RMSE, confusion matrices, etc. in a generic way without having to recall the usage of various modeling methods.

However, some models have unique reporting outcomes. For example, with a boosted tree model one can compare the in-sample *vs.* out-sample error-rate as a function of the number of trees to test for overfitting. Naturally this report would not make sense with other methods that do not use trees.

Is there a way I can use CARET to access these model-specific reports (maybe by accessing the modeling object generated directly)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `train` function in `caret` returns an S3 list object.  On of the items in this list is called `finalModel`.  This item is just the fitted object in it's native form.  So if you trained a gbm using `train` and stored it in an object called `my.fit`, then `summary(my.fit$finalModel)` would use the `summary.gbm` method from the `gbm` package and show you the relative variable importance.